# Why doesn't this code throw an error in Java?

Tags: java, substring

```
String s = "Hola";
System.out.println(s.substring(4));
```

4 is out of bounds, yet no error is thrown.

Why is that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the javadoc say?

Comment: "IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex is negative or larger than the length of this String object." from the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)).  4 is not larger than the length of the string.

Comment: *"IndexOutOfBoundsException  if * {@code beginIndex} is negative or **larger than the  length** of this {@code String} object."*  ...

Answer (score 5):

Think of the argument to `String.substring()` as the number of characters to *skip*. So skipping 4 characters in `"Hola"` yields the empty string.

```
"Hola".substring(0) => "Hola"
"Hola".substring(1) => "ola"
"Hola".substring(2) => "la"
"Hola".substring(3) => "a"
"Hola".substring(4) => ""
```

The lowest argument for which an exception will be thrown on a 4-character string is 5.

Answer (score 0):

The index of Strings starts at 0 and not 1.
For example, in string "Hola",

index 0 would be H

index 1 would be o

index 2 would be l

index 3 would be a

Notice that there is no index 4. This is why you are getting an error.
instead, change  it to

```
System.out.println(s.substring(3));
```